# Piecewise regression : Reproducibility problems on breakpoints detection in segmented R package

Tags: r, regression, breakpoints, piecewise, reproducible-research

I'm trying to fit a 3 pieces regression on my data with the help of the `segmented` package, and I'm a bit lost...

First : here is a reproducible example :

```
y=c(520.0000, 620.0000, 653.3333, 853.3333, 1220.0000, 1553.3333, 1586.6667, 1586.6667, 1586.6667, 1586.6667, 1586.6667)
x=c(33320, 41020, 49020, 56920, 69220, 76320, 86320, 95420, 103720, 111520, 120320)
plot(y~x)
out=lm(y~x)
```

My data with 2 visible breakpoints :

[image]

**- First I tried specifying the known number of breakpoints with K=2 :**

```
mdl2=segmented(out, seg.Z =~x, psi=NA, control=seg.control(K=2,n.boot=0,it.max=500,stop.if.error=FALSE,display=T))
plot(mdl2)
points(y~x)
```

Which gives me, a 1 breakpoint result :
[image]

**- But if I set `2<K<8` (so a wrong value...), I'm able to detect the right number of breakpoints :**

[image]

**- And a last point which puzzles me :**

If I set K=4, the display=T option show me a result with 3 breakpoints, but in the function output I still have two breakpoints...

[image]

******EDIT OF THE 09/19/2016******

I tried also by specifying `psi` directly as I've some priors on the breakpoints location (but it's not my goal), and the results are still really bad with `segmented`...

For some regression I've to run the function many times before the algorithm success to end with a solution. Also, the solutions proposed have often reproducibility problems...

Does anyone know a way to robustly estimate these breakpoints ? It looks like my data are not that hard to fit, isn't it ?

Comment: i also tried to use segmented function and I gave up because of reproducibility problems of the results

Comment: @agenis : and which one you used instead ? ;)
I used `lm.br` package before, but it's limited to a one breakpoint regression.

Comment: well actually I only needed one breakpoint so i coded the loop myself, based on Cross validation error. And anyway eventually a lowess model came out much better than changepoint model. ;-)